# Double Integral $\iint\limits_D\frac{dx\,dy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ where $D=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2\le1,\space x+y\ge1\}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, bounds-of-integration

Let $D=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2 : x^2+y^2\le1,\space x+y\ge1\}$.  The integral to be calculated over $D$ is the following:
\begin{equation}
\iint_D \frac{dx\,dy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
\end{equation}

I do not know how to approach the problem.  I have tried integrating the function in cartesian coordinates but it doesn't seem to work out. I have also tried the variable change $u=x^2+y^2$ and $v=x+y$ (with the associated jacobian transformation) and again I cannot obtain the result.

Comment: Rotate everything 45-degrees clockwise; the boundary 'x + y = 1' becomes the vertical line 'x = 1/sqrt(2)'. Now it should be very easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Among skills of a technical (as opposed to conceptual) nature  that are used in calculus, among the ones in which most students are weakest is technical details of trigonometry.  When changing this to polar coordinates, $x^2+y^2$ becomes $r^2$ and $dx\,dy$ becomes $r\,dr\,d\theta$ and the boundary at $x^2+y^2=1$ becomes $r=1$, but what is one to do with $x+y\ge 1$?  Drawing the picture, you see that that's a diagonal line going through both the highest point on the circle (the one with the largest $y$-coordinate) and the rightmost point on the circle (the one with the largest $x$-coordinate).  And the constraint says $r\cos\theta+r\sin\theta \ge 1$.  So you want $\theta$ to go from $0$ to $\pi/2$ and $r$ to go from **something** to $1$.  You can write $r\ge\dfrac 1 {\cos\theta+\sin\theta}$. Then you have
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_{1/(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)}^1 \frac{r \, dr \,d\theta}{r^4} = \int_0^{\pi/2}\left( \int_{1/(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)}^1 \frac{dr}{r^3} \right) d\theta.
$$
The inside integral is
$$
\left.\frac{-1}{2r^2} \right|_{r:=1/(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)}^1 = \frac{-1} 2 +  \frac 1 {2(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)^2}.
$$
Then you need to integrate that from $0$ to $\pi/2$.

Alternatively, you could note that by circular symmetry, the integral is the same as
$$
\iint_E \frac{dx\,dy}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \text{ where } E=\left\{(x,y): x^2+y^2 \le 1\ \&\  x\ge \frac{\sqrt 2} 2 \right\}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: try out with polar coordinates $x= r \cos(\theta) $, $y = r \sin(\theta) $, just be careful when "changing" the domain $D$.

Comment: I'm still unsure of the boundaries for r.  Will the be from $1-rcos\theta$ to $1$?

Comment: Not exactly, we have $0 \le 1-x \le y $, now substitute and divide (be careful about sign changes). If you have trouble using only the algebraic equation, try to draw a picture: draw our circle and the line, we are interested in the area above the line but under the circle. Fix a $ 0 \le \theta \le \pi/2 $, identify the segments with length $ \sin(\theta) $ and $\cos(\theta)$. Keeping in mind that points on the line satisfy $ 1- x = y$ use some trigonometry to get $r = r(\theta) $. Once you get an explicit $r(\theta)$ we have $ r(\theta) \le r \le 1 $. I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 2):

Transforming to polar coordinates $(\rho,\phi)$, we find that on $x+y=1$ we have $\rho =1/(\cos(\phi)+\sin(\phi))$.  Therefore, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_D \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dx\,dy&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_{1/(\sin(\phi)+\cos(\phi))}^1 \frac{1}{\rho^3}\,d\rho\,d\phi\\\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(2\phi)\,d\phi\\\\
&=\frac12
\end{align}$$

Comment: @johnmelon I've edited to include the method for determining the lower bound on $\rho$.